# How to append the content in the file for chef cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I'm new in chef and cookbook.
I'm creating a cookbook, and I want to append at the end of file some contents (text).
At the moment, I'm using:

```
file "#{node['dir']}/#{params[:name]}.txt" do
   content "my full text"
end
```

but I must always append in the "content" the old content because it will overwrite.
Is there another way to append contents?

Thank you
pasquy

Comment: Note that simply appending text to a file is not considered good practice as it isn't [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) (i.e. you can't run your recipe again and get the same end-result as before which most people consider rather crucial for recipes). Whenever possible, you should try to manage whole files with Chef as that is *much* easier to control than checking existing files and selectively adding content.

Comment: Ok, thank you Holger. FYI I'm working on subversion authorization and I need to append in the dav_svn.load apache file the text "LoadModule ... mod_authz_svn.so".

Comment: Apache has the concept of config directories where it loads all the files that are in there (e.g. `/etc/httpd/config.d`). Just create a new file with your content in that directory (or a similar one depending on your OS, on debian/ubuntu its `/etc/apache2/mods-available` with a symlink in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`).

Comment: You are right, I thought to create a new conf file, but in my case, the authz_svn must be loaded before dav_svn module, and apache server reads all conf files in alphabetic order. I accept any suggestion.

Comment: So? just create a file with a filename that comes alphabetically before the existing one.

Comment: Is this the right way? The module is named authz_svn. I can try to named this authz_svn module as dav_svn_authz; I'll let you know and thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: If I want to use the apache_module.rb file (of the apache cookbook), I must add in the server.rb file this line: apache_module 'authz_svn' (to create the file within LoadModule ... mod_authz_svn.so) but the file is named mod_authz_svn.

Comment: You can add the `filename` parameter to the `apache_module` resource like `apache_module "authz_svn" do; filename "mod_authz_svn.so"; end`. Have a look at the [definition](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apache2/blob/master/definitions/apache_module.rb).

Comment: Thank you Holger, it works; these are the lines: `apache_module "dav_svn_authz" do; 
    filename "mod_authz_svn.so";
    identifier "authz_svn_module";
end`. so my new file is named dav_svn_authz.load

Comment: Did any of the proposed solutions help? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use direct Ruby to do this. There's a built-in class in Chef called [FileEdit](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/util/file_edit.rb) that will handle this for you. Specifically, you probably want [`insert_line_if_no_match`](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/util/file_edit.rb#L69-L73).

Comment: Using the inbuilt class does make more sense. Was unaware of that at the time of my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could you use direct ruby code if you wanted like

```
open('myfile.out', 'a') do |f|
f << "and again ...\n"
end
```

That could be done in a ruby_block provider if you wanted. [This link describes how to use that type of block](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_ruby_block.html)

Another alternative is to read in your files contents and then concatenate that with the updated string in your current block?

Comment: Thank you ... it works. How can I parameterize the myfile.out path file?

Comment: same way as you did before

    open(@#{node['dir']}/#{params[:name]}.txt",'a') do |f|

Should do it

Answer (score 1):

If you only use ruby code, then chef will write contents at load time of your recipe BEFORE checking any dependencies. And definitely not during convergence.

A combination of ruby and chef will do the trick.

```
file = File.open(#{node['dir']}/#{params[:name]}.txt, "rb")
existingContents = file.read
newContents = existingContents + "my full text"

file "#{node['dir']}/#{params[:name]}.txt" do
   content newContents
end
```

So the idea is build the string at load time, pass that string to chef and let chef change the contents at right stage during convergence.